# Find the GIT Repository in specific directory and exec git bundle command

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, git, find

I am using ubuntu 12.04 TLS in which i have a git repository in a specific directory, what i am trying is to take the scheduled backup of the repository and place it in specific directory that can be mailed.

In the process i get to know to find all the git repository in specific directory 
by googling i found this below command

```
find /home/mysys/D/ -name .git -type d -prune
```

but it contain the path as

> /home/mysys/D/testing/.git

which list all the git files associated in the directory and it is working, but what i need to execute git bundle create directoryname.bundle --all  to make it more automated in which i tried the following

```
find /home/mysys/D/ -name .git -type d -prune -exec git bundle create test.bundle --all {} \;
```

The above bash script returns

```
fatal: Invalid gitfile format: .git
```

How to do this to make it work robust.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to be *in* the git-controlled directory when `git bundle` is executed, so use `find ... -execdir ... \;`

```
find /home/mysys/D/ -type d -name .git -prune -execdir git bundle create backup.bundle --all \;
```

That will create a backup.bundle in all these directories. From there you can move those, or process them with more scripting. But the bundling side of things is handled.

Comment: Thanks oli it is working is there a way to make the basename as bundlename along with today date is it possible?

Comment: if the folder name as test then test_31mar2016.bundle like that?

Comment: Sure, wangle your execdir statement around to something like: `sh -c 'git bundle create $(basename $(dirname {}))"_"$(date +"...")".bundle" --all'`. (this needs work, ie to format the date)

Comment: Hi tried this one but it returns like ._....bundle

Comment: i can able to view this using show hidden files

Comment: did i miss something?

Comment: Needs a bit more tweaking. `$(basename $(readlink -f {}/..))` should get your the parent directory name.

Comment: Awesome Oli it is working i can able to automate this stuff using crontab -e with new cron job  :) Thanks it is working flawlessly :)

Comment: Sure but you'd need to wrap it in another shell. You'd be better off writing a standalone bash script that calls your find command, an then calling that script from cron.